# How to select text fields using tab key in java

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, tabs, keyboard

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJu4p.jpg]

When I press tab key on the keyboard I want to select my text fields in above order.how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean "Tab Index" ? Show us your related codes

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Customizing Focus Traversal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#customFocusTraversal) for a working example similar to what you want.

Comment: Do you mean "Tab Index" ? yep

Comment: Swing doesn't support that concept. Read the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example....

```
package com.Demo;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TabTest extends JFrame {
    public TabTest() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        setSize(300, 300);
        setTitle("JTextArea TAB DEMO");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        //
        // Add key listener to change the TAB behaviour in
        // JTextArea to transfer focus to other component forward
        // or backward.
        //
        textArea.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
                    if (e.getModifiers() > 0) {
                        textArea.transferFocusBackward();
                    } else {
                        textArea.transferFocus();
                    }
                    e.consume();
                }
            }
        });

        getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(passwordField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TabTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings.

Answer (score 0):

```
jTextField1.setNextFocusableComponent(jTextField2);
jTextField2.setNextFocusableComponent(jTextField3);
jTextField3.setNextFocusableComponent(jTextField4);
jTextField4.setNextFocusableComponent(jTextField5);
```

try this :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21795107)

Comment: @rickvdbosch yes it is. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256360/6296561

Comment: when typing in jTextField1 you wont pressed tab clicked the jTextField5 ?
put in constructor this code
jTextField1.setNextFocusableComponent(jTextField5);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
txtfld.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {                
            txtfld.setText("aaa");
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
           ...
        }
    });
```

[see](https://coderanch.com/t/482913/java/Tab-Key-Binding-JTextField) more complete code.